# Passing the getUnsubscriptionLink method to the Newsletter Subscription Success Email

Tags: email, newsletter

I would like to make it possible to unsubscribe however with the arrival of an email about the success of the newsletter signup. But the problem I encountered is that I don't have access to the getUnsubscriptionLink method there. Someone direct me how I can do this?

This code doesn't work

```php
<p class="center">
{{trans "At %store_name, we care about your privacy. If you do not want to receive notifications about new offers <a href="%unsubscribe_link"> click here</a>." store_name=$store.getFrontendName() unsubscribe_link=$subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink() |raw}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Newsletter Subscription Success Email, then you can use this code.

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">Unsubscribe</a>
```